# Problems with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong in eclipse based on two problems I can't seem to get around.

The first is the fact that the Eclipse editor severely grays out field names, labels or whatever, sometimes only showing commas between these items. Others have a black text background. All this makes it extremely difficult to read and even worse to edit.

The other is the fact that if I "`Build Project`" for project A then switch to "`Build Project`" for project B , the `Problems` window stays with the errors for project A.

I've closed and re-opened the problems view. I've closed and re-opened Eclipse. Finally, I've run '`Clean`'. All these things do nothing to change or correct the `Problems` view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck on the very first sample app in developer.android.com.

Comment: your eclipse malfunctions, plugins may be missing... download a fresh one ADT!

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using and on which platform(OS)?

Comment: Are the contents of the Problems View set to show problems from the currently selected project only? How are you "switching" between projects? Can you show an image of what you're describing in the editor?

Comment: Would you mind posting what other plugins you have installed in your eclipse?